# Python: Recusively remove file folders greater than x days old

Tags: python

I have the following directory structure:

/year/month/day/file.txt

and what I'd like to is to delete entire directories where the /year/month/day is greater than x number of days.

Additionally, if the x number of days exceeds the days in the current month, it deletes the day/ folders from the previous month.

For example: If today is January 15th, and the x number of days to remove is 20, then the script should remove everything but the last 5 days in December.

Any ideas?

Comment: How can a date be greater than a number? What does that mean?

Comment: I tried pulling the day component of date.today() and deleting the day/ folders that qualified while decrementing a counter, and then subtracting the month component (as necessary), and then removing the day/ from previous month using the remaining counter value.

Somehow I just feel like it's rather ugly and was wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: I still don't understand the rule you're giving. If it's January 15, and you want to remove things that are more than 20 days old, why are you removing the last 5 days in December, instead of everything _but_ the last 5 days in December?

Comment: @CarlSagan: Show us the code instead of describing it, and tell us what it did wrong instead of making us guess.

Comment: @CarlSagan: OK. If you wanted to delete only the most recent directories, iterating date objects and turning them into directory paths that match would make sense. But if you want to delete all _but_ the most recent directories, it doesn't. How would you know when to stop looking? Iterate all dates back to 1970 just in case? That's why I turned it around, walking the directories and turning them into dates. Does that make sense?

Comment: @CarlSagan: If 45 < x < 0, I think the number line flipped poles while I was sleeping. :) (I get what you mean, but be careful about mistakes like that—Python won't get what you mean, and, from my experience, those are the hardest mistakes the debug, because no matter how much you stare at them, they don't look wrong…)

Comment: @abarnert Good point. Currently, 45 > x > 0, but I shouldn't assume the bounds to continue indefinitely! :)

Comment: @CarlSagan: If only 45 < x < 1 were true for some x… I just spent 35 minutes debugging a stupid bash script where I was checking all files that were not aged less than -1 days, or some such conglomeration of too many double negatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for year in os.listdir('.'):
    for month in os.listdir(year):
        for day in os.listdir(os.path.join(year, month)):
            date = datetime.date(int(year), int(month), int(day))
```

Now you can use the utilities in the [`date`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) class. When you've decided to remove a entire directory, use [`shutil.rmtree`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree).

For example:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
for year in os.listdir('.'):
    for month in os.listdir(year):
        for day in os.listdir(os.path.join(year, month):
            date = datetime.date(int(year), int(month), int(day))
            age = today - date
            if age > datetime.timedelta(days=20):
                shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(year, month, day))
```

Comment: Former comment retracted :)